# Counting Dublicates in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I have a column of names (200+) in one Excel-sheet. Some of the names are double. I would like to find out how many different names I have, so I need a function that counts identical entry's just once.
Is it possible to write that in a formula? I don't want to use vba.
I would be very happy if someone could give me a clue.
Greetings!

Comment: This will depend on your version, what version do you have?

Comment: or with older: `=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A200,A1:A200))`

Comment: `COUNTA(UNIQUE(A1:A200))` for o365